# Select rows that do NOT have a DISTINCT value in SQLALCHEMY

Tags: sql, database, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Can someone suggest a method for selecting rows that do not have a unique value for a column?
I don't have an active project, it's more like a question in my mind. So I don't have a db schema to share.

For example: If I have five records, with 1 record that has CustNo = 7, 1 record that has CustNo = 9, and three records that have CustNo = 11, I only want to select the three rows that have CustNo = 11

Comment: Something like definitely won't work >> Table.query.filter(~db.session.query(db.func.distinct(Table.CustNo))).all()

Answer (score 1):

You could use a SQL query like

```sql
SELECT * FROM invoice
WHERE CustNo IN (
    SELECT CustNo FROM invoice
    GROUP BY CustNo
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

which in SQLAlchemy's SQL Expression Language would be

```py
qry = invoice.select().where(
    invoice.c.CustNo.in_(
        select([invoice.c.CustNo])
        .group_by("CustNo")
        .having(func.count(text("*")) > 1)
    )
)
```